# Doubts on moving RDS instance from EC2-Classic to VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm using Oracle RDS in the classic configuration pre-VPC era.

I have created rules on the RDS security group to allow EC2 public IPs from VPC instances to access the DB.

I have used all the 20 allowed IP address and *referencing other SGs from RDS SG doesn't seem to work*.

So, i need to move my RDS oracle instance from EC2-Classic to a VPC, i understand the overall procedure but i have some important questions not found on AWS docs:

- Is there any downtime ? If so, how much?
- The database endpoint will change after the migration?
- EC2-VPC instances could still using the db endpoint transparently?

If anyone already did this migration i would like to hear the overall experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will answer myself as i have done the migration anyway,

**Is there any downtime ? If so, how much?**

There is a downtime, it was something like 5 minutes in my case
We also made a hardware upgrade also on the migration and the resizing of the disk was made with no downtime.

**The database endpoint will change after the migration?**

It didn't change, the endpoint for any RDS database do not change ever.

**EC2-VPC instances could still using the db endpoint transparently?**

Yes, i did not have to restart my services. The internal DNS of AWS started
to resolve the RDS endpoint to a internal VPC address after the migration. 
For the hosts outside the VPC the endpoint resolves to a internet public address.

I also created a special VPC security group and gave access to all the host inside the VPC just in case, i'm not sure this is actually necessary.